# tikz: not so precise graphic

Tags: tikz-pgf

Do you see the point `(0.78951,1.38506)` is slightly below the previous one, while it should be above?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,systeme} % Typical maths resource packages
    \usepackage{color}                    % For creating coloured text and background
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usetkzobj{all}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  grid, grid style=dashed,
  xticklabel style={rotate=90},
  ymin=1.33,ymax=1.39,
  extra y ticks={1.33,1.35,1.37},            % <---
  xmax=1,xmin=0,
  extra x ticks={0},            % <---
  xtick={0,0.20594,0.38019,0.62664,0.78951,1},
  minor tick num=1,
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,                   % <---
  %axis on top,                  % <---
  xlabel=$x_1$,ylabel=$n_D$,
  x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
  x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                      fixed relative,
                      /pgf/number format/precision=5
                     },
  style={thick}
               ]
  \addplot+[color=red,mark=*,mark options={draw=red,fill=green},thick,smooth]
    coordinates {
    (0.00000, 1.33300)(0.20594,1.37003)(0.38019,1.37944)(0.62664,1.38502)(0.78951,1.38506)(1.00000,1.38511)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it just me, or is it really like that? In this case, do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try removing `smooth` and see what happens?

Comment: If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). In this instance, quark67 clearly deserves the tick, I think.

Answer (score 23):

It's a optical effect because the slope of the red curve at point (0.65664, 1.38502) is too big relative to the (real) slope between the points (0.65664, 1.38502) and (0.78951,1.38506). You can see in this magnified screenshot (with the blue horizontal line) that the point (0.78951,1.38506) is really above the previous one.

Note the adding of the line `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` in the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,systeme} % Typical maths resource packages
    \usepackage{color}                    % For creating coloured text and background
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usetkzobj{all}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  grid, grid style=dashed,
  xticklabel style={rotate=90},
  ymin=1.33,ymax=1.39,
  extra y ticks={1.33,1.35,1.37},            % <---
  xmax=1,xmin=0,
  extra x ticks={0},            % <---
  xtick={0,0.20594,0.38019,0.62664,0.78951,1},
  minor tick num=1,
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,                   % <---
  %axis on top,                  % <---
  xlabel=$x_1$,ylabel=$n_D$,
  x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
  x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                      fixed relative,
                      /pgf/number format/precision=5
                     },
  style={thick}
               ]
  \addplot+[color=red,mark=*,mark options={draw=red,fill=green},thick,smooth]
    coordinates {
    (0.00000, 1.33300)(0.20594,1.37003)(0.38019,1.37944)(0.62664,1.38502)(0.78951,1.38506)(1.00000,1.38511)
    };
    \draw[ultra thin, blue] (0.62,1.38410)--(0.8,1.38410) ;
    \draw[ultra thin, violet] (0.62664,1.38502) -- (0.70,1.38570);
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

You could reduce this effect by reducing the `tension` (by default, it is 0.55):
`\addplot+[color=red,mark=*,mark options={draw=red,fill=green},thick,smooth,tension=0.25]`

give:
[image]

Answer (score 10):

The point at 0.79 is not actually lower. Rather the interpolated graph keeps increasing after the point at 0.62 and this makes it *look* as if the point as 0.79 is lower. You can see that this is the case by magnifying the graph and just looking at these two points. The image below shows that the point at 0.79, on the right, is indeed slightly higher than the point at 0.62:

[image]

[This is really an extended comment, except that you can't put images into comments...]